# Convert Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership such that I can write it to the notes field

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I am writing a PowerShell script to automate putting users on a leave of absence. As part of this process, we remove the user from their DLs if it is a long absence to stop them from coming back to thousands of emails.

I am planning to saving the list of members to the notes field under the telephone tab, so I can easily restore it manually when they get back (one automation step at a time)

I have no problem pulling a list of of distribution groups with:

```
 Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user | Where-Object GroupCategory -eq Distribution | select name
```

The part I run into trouble with is when I try to save it to the notes field with:

```
Set-ADUser $user -replace @{info=(Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user | Where-Object GroupCategory -eq Distribution |select name)}
```

I get the error:

```
Set-ADUser : Invalid type 'System.Management.Automation.PSObject'.
```

I have tried massaging the data into shape with -split and -join, but either I'm not doing it right or these are not the right commands. ConvertTo-CSV "works", but adds a lot of extra cruft.

**How can I transform this data so that the telephone tab will accept it?** My prefered format is something I can use to copy/paste the groups back in afterwords ie. group1;group2;group3 etc. (I will also take comments that the way I am approaching this is all wrong and that method *xyz* is much better.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I don't mean to state the obvious, but you are trying to paste in a Powershell object, where the `info` attribute of an AD user will only accept strings. You need to convert the list of group memberships into a string first, and add the logic yourself for putting your delimiter of choice in between each group name, be it a comma, semicolon or newline character.

```
Foreach($grp In Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $usr | Where-Object GroupCategory -eq Distribution) 
{ 
    $GroupString += $grp.Name + ';' 
}
$GroupString = $GroupString.TrimEnd(';') # Remove the last delimiter off the end
Set-ADUser $usr -Replace @{info=$GroupString}
```

Comment: Thanks! I got so fixated on PowerShell having a command for everything that I didn't even think of a loop. Now I know for next time.

Answer (score 1):

You can also pipe the output to:

```
Select-Object -ExpandProperty name
```

This only allows you to select one property, but PowerShell will convert it to a string.